# Query Oracle database through python

Tags: rhel, python, oracle-database, sqlplus

Background: New to python.

I have a high security client.  Anything on the O/S must go through a lengthy (nearly impossible in some cases) process to be approved by the IA department.

I want to convert my bash scripts to python2:

1. I don't want to ask to install python3
2. I don't want to ask to install  cx_Oracle

In bash I could do something like this:

```
echo "select user from dual;"|${SQLPLUS} > ${TEMPFILE}
```

Is there a way to do something similar in python2 with the basic tools that are part of RHEL7?

Comment: python2 will be a security risk in a few months ( https://github.com/python/devguide/pull/344 ) . Having a high security client and rollout python2  is not the correct way to do

Comment: @EchoMike444  Interesting.  So you think I can make a case for python3?

Comment: and RHEL 7 is a little too old for  my taste ...  https://access.redhat.com/articles/3078#RHEL8

Comment: you have already oracle deployed , what is the issue to install cx_oracle ? you must ask your client the full list of sofware you can use ?

Comment: @EchoMike444  The issue is speed.  Rush to get something done  vs  the months it will take to get it approved.  IA will have to go through cx_oracle looking for whatever they look for...  EDIT: cx_oracle isn't on the very short list of SW

Comment: when you call sqlpus in bash how you store the password ? this is a arg  in the command  line ? if yes that will be a big security risk because password will be visible with a simple `ps` command

Comment: @EchoMike444  sqlplus / as sysdba

Comment: Don’t worry about python2 in RHEL7. It’ll be supported until the end of life for RHEL7, past when upstream stops supporting it.  I wouldn’t start any new projects with it, but you can ignore people saying it’s a security risk. Red Hat will continue to provide security fixes. It’s a core part of RHEL7.